# Let A be an infinite set. Show that there exists a proper subset B of A such that |A| = |B|. Does your proof use the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let A be an infinite set. Show that there exists a proper subset B of A such that |A| = |B|. Does your proof use the Axiom of Choice?

Any ideas on how to prove this?

Comment: How are you defining infinite set? Because this is one possible definition of it. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Pick any $x\in A$. Is $A \setminus \{x\}$ infinite?